# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I am created an android app & is running above API level 21.
But not running on below API level 21.

Here is error log:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl.class
Help me through

Below is my gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*******"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(exclude: 'android-support-*.jar', dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':simple-crop-image-lib')
    //    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:+'
    compile project(':material-login')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Compile the build with**

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

In Your **AndroidManifest.xml** add this lines **android:name**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >
```

And In your **build.gradle** also add

```
dexOptions {
    //incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}


packagingOptions {
     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
}
```

Comment: you should be also  multiDexEnabled true

Comment: Try compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

      targetSdkVersion 24 and


24.1.1 instead of 23.4.0

Comment: check out question & still problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120122/discussion-between-mohit-dahiya-and-er-arjun-saini).